# Why is a cylindrical Gaussian surface more desirable to derive the electric field at some point from a plane of charge than a rectangular prism?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauss-law

I'm told that, like in videos such as [this one,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rRWQlGleNM) a cylinder is the Gaussian surface to use when trying to find the electric field at some point away from a plane of charge. I don't see what's wrong with doing this, but I don't see what's so great about it either. Why can't you draw a rectangular prism normal through the plane instead of a cylinder and carry on with the same derivation? Why a cylinder? In my mind, it would do the same thing.

Another thing, actually. Why is it that, when the lecturer encloses the point with a cylinder from plane to point, that he includes the cylinder going *under* the plane as well? Why is that necessary at all? Why is the surface drawn above *and* below the plane?

Answer (score 1):

To your first question, you can use a cylinder or rectangle-shape, or any shape for that matter which has two areas perpendicular to the plane of charge and the other area is orthogonal. The Gaussian surface is set up that way so that $\vec E$ can be readily moved outside the surface integral.

To you second question, you never want to place the Gaussian surface along the plane itself, because then the electric field through it is undefined. The Gaussian surface should always goes on one side of the plane or the other, in order to add up the electric field penetrating it. It is also useful to place the Gaussian surface on the other side of the plane so that a region of the charged plane is enclosed, and the total flux is non-zero.

Comment: Boom. Thanks for this. Oh, can you elaborate why the electric field would be undefined? Also, why would the total flux be non zero if the region of the charged plane is enclosed top and bottom equally? I still don’t get yet why it’s beneficial to have it enclosing the top and bottom.

Comment: The total flux is non-zero if there is charge enclosed. The gaussian surface should enclose some of the plane so that there is some outward flux (E*A), from there solve for E. Maybe you can put your Gaussian surface through the plane of charge and make a statement like: "The Gaussian surface cuts through the plane of charges evenly so that half the charge is on one side and the other half is on the other side...", but as you might imagine, that's not recommended (although it works out mathematically).